# Arrgh! grsync not working. Again

Tags: mount, grsync

I'd like to use it daily for a limited number of my most commone directories.  But I can't.

I'd especially like to use it for all common directories just before I travel.  Can't do that either.

It was great when it finally started working, but no more.  Now I choose a multi-job process, it finishes in less than a minute.  When it first happened I thought I just hadn't changed that many files.  But after a few times like that, I checked the destination drive -- and nothing had been updated.  All old file dates.

I suppose this is related, maybe The cause, but I don't know what to do about it either.

I'm also getting errors mounting the NAS drive. Why?  I haven't done anything to the system (besides try to use it). That had happened before but stopped "back in the day" and grsync started working.  This was months ago and I forget the details.

I have a bookmark to the destination directory on the NAS, but I get the mounting error when I click on it.  I can get onto the NAS by logging on with username/pswrd.  I can look at all the directories on it in Nautilus.  But rsync still does its false "success" thing.

What can I check?

Comment: The mounting error starts with header "Could not display "smb://[path]"  and then "Error: Failed to mount Windows share: Invalid argument
Please select another viewer and try again."

Answer (score 0):

Use Your File Manager, Left Pane, Other Locations.
Add your Share as a Registered User.  Login & Password.
Use the File Manager to drill down to your Location/Share.
It takes a long time.  Open the "=>[Rsync Output:]" button to see the transfer.